# Renderizar informações do usuário atual

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Estou fazendo um sistema de login básico com javascript, a minha intenção é quando o usuário clicar para fazer login carrega para página do usuário que tem informações do usuário atual. Estou usando localStorage para armazenamento.

Como eu faço para renderizar informações do banco de dados do cliente?

```
const ls = localStorage.getItem('usuarios')

let lista = []
let id = 0
function cadastro() {
    let nome = document.getElementById('nome').value
    let idade = document.getElementById('idade').value

    id++
    lista.push({
        id: id,
        nome: nome,
        idade: idade
    })
    save()
    window.location.href = 'login.html'
}

function save() {
    localStorage.setItem('usuarios', JSON.stringify(lista))
}


function login() {
    let nome = document.getElementById('nome').value
    let idade = document.getElementById('idade').value
    let texto = document.getElementById('texto');
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuarios')).map(usuario => {
        if (nome == usuario.nome && idade == usuario.idade) {
            window.location.href = 'usuario.html';
        } else {
            texto.innerHTML = 'Nome ou senha inválidos!'
        }
    })
}
//document.getElementById('nomeUsuario').innerHTML = `Olá ${}`
```

Comment: Muito estranho guardar sua lista de usuários/login no localstorage. Porque o localstorage fica no browser que está acessando essa página. Então cada um que acessa esse site teria sua própria lista de usuários. O lugar adequado para guardar usuários é uma base de dados no servidor.

Comment: É só um exemplo!

Answer (score 0):

Quando fazes login tens de gravar o ID do usuário atual e depois usas esse ID para ir buscar as informações na página do usuário.

```
function login() {
    let nome = document.getElementById('nome').value
    let idade = document.getElementById('idade').value
    let texto = document.getElementById('texto');
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuarios')).map(usuario => {
        if (nome == usuario.nome && idade == usuario.idade) {
            localStorage.setItem("usuarioAtual", usuario.id);
            window.location.href = 'usuario.html';
        } else {
            texto.innerHTML = 'Nome ou senha inválidos!'
        }
    })
}

function usuarioAtual() {
    var id = localStorage.getItem("usuarioAtual");
    var usuario = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuarios')).find(usuario => {
        return usuario.id == id;
    });

    document.getElementById("nomeUsuario").innerHTML = `Olá ${usuario.nome}`;
}
```